# (Wordpress) How to add a simple text to the contents of a specific category (php)

Tags: php, wordpress

the following code in my function.php can almost do the job nice and clean to all single pages. the problem is I want it to be filtered for a specific category ID:

```
function wp_add_to_content( $content ) {
    if( is_single() && ! empty( $GLOBALS['post'] ) ) {
        if ( $GLOBALS['post']->ID == get_the_ID() ) {
            $content .= 'Your new content here';
        }
    }
    return $content;
}
add_filter('the_content', 'wp_add_to_content');
```

Comment: Firstly, the line `if ( $GLOBALS['post']->ID == get_the_ID() )` isn't doing anything because both are getting the id for the current post. When you say a specific category ID, do you mean the general category, or a specific term in the category? Also, is it a default WP category or a custom taxonomy?

Comment: @FluffyKitten yeah exactly. this code displays the text for all posts (in single pages) and that's why I said I needed a filter for a specific category and by specific I meant when you go to Posts > Categories and create a new category and when you hover your cursor over that category link you can see the ID. I thought that ID could be used for the filter in question and that way the text can only be displayed for the posts of that category we have created. Akshay Shah already made one... thanks for your response anyway.

Comment: Akshay's answer is actually incorrect. I'll post the correct way to do it in a minute...

Comment: Your question implies that you want to add the content *only* for posts in a specific category - Akshay's answer adds it for *all* posts, and duplicates it for category posts - was that what you actually required?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use `get_the_category` and examine the results - Wordpress already has a function to check if your post is in a category: `has_category`. The advantage of this over `get_the_category` is that

1. you don't need the code to loop through all results to comparing the id (this is the part that is wrong in the other answer - it  will only work if your post has *one* single category)
2. You can use not just the ID, but also the slug or name
3. You can check for multiple categories

The code you need is very simple, you just need to change one line!

```
function wp_add_to_content( $content ) {
    if( is_single() && ! empty( $GLOBALS['post'] ) ) {

        /* pass an array with the IDs/names/slugs of the categories to check for, e.g. */
        if ( has_category( array(12) ) )
            $content .= 'Your new content here';
    }
    return $content;
}
add_filter('the_content', 'wp_add_to_content');
```

**UPDATE:**

Even though it wasn't in your question, if you actually want to include the content on all posts *as well*, you just need to do this:

```
function wp_add_to_content( $content ) {
    if( is_single() && ! empty( $GLOBALS['post'] ) ) {

        $content .= 'Your new content here';

        if ( has_category( array(12) ) )
            $content .= '<br>Your new content here';
    }
    return $content;
}
add_filter('the_content', 'wp_add_to_content');
```

Comment: I put my cat ID and it crashed with a syntax error ! I even replaced it with the category slug (say: video-clips) and it didn't work...

Comment: @Timitom Sorry, I missed a `)` at the end of the `if(has_category...)` line, I'll update the answer now. Also, can you confirm your requirements - do you want to add text to *every* post? And do you want to duplicate it for the category posts?

Comment: In one word FANTASTIC... short, precise and simple. I can easily add any cat ID or slugs that I want with a simple comma. thank you so much.. and as for the global post.. yea that's not what I requested but hey it wouldn't hurt to have the global as well, you know. say I wanted to add a text to every post then putting each and every cat ID would make it messy for another if statement

Comment: @Timitom Glad it works for you! Yes, its much simpler than trying to manage all the looping & comparing of ids yourself... especially if you have multiple categories per post or want to add more categories in future.  If WP has a built-in function for something, it's usually the best option :)

Answer (score 0):

Modified your code idealy  this condition is never making any sense because it always getting the id. $GLOBALS['post']->ID == get_the_ID()

```
function wp_add_to_content( $content ) {
    if( is_single() && ! empty( $GLOBALS['post'] ) ) {
        if ( $GLOBALS['post']->ID == get_the_ID() ) {
            $content .= 'Your new content here';
        }
        //getting the current post
        global $post;
        $category_detail=get_the_category( $post->ID );
        if(!empty($category_detail))
        {
            $catId = $category_detail[0]->term_id;
            // instead of 2 put your category id 
            if($catId == 2 && $catId != 0 )
            {
                $content .= 'Your new content here';
            }
        }
    }
    return $content;
}
add_filter('the_content', 'wp_add_to_content');
```

Note : above code is for only default post not for custom taxonomy for custom taxonomy

Comment: excellent... however there's only one minor issue that's not a big deal. when I have both texts in that specific category they would stick together and there's no space between the two. I had to use <br> for one of them. is there a way to add a custom space somewhere in the codes ?

Comment: This will only work if the post has one single category. It also is unnecessarily complicated and limited, just use `has_category` - WP's function specifically for this purpose. Also, it isn't filtering it for just the category - its actually adding if for all posts, and duplicating it for category posts, which was not in the OPs requirements.